Lectura de JSON con pySpark
Quiero realizar un análisis del rendimiento de jugadores en diferentes partidos para determinar los mejores según ciertas características. La información básica de jugadores y de los partidos esta en csv que puedo leer sin problema, pero el rendimiento de los equipos y jugadores en dichos partidos esta en un archivo json el cual no se como leer usando pyspark.
Intente usar la siguiente linea, que es como leo los csv:
df2 = spark.read.json("/FileStore/tables/season_stats.json")
df2.printSchema()

Cuando ejecuto esta, aparece el siguiente resultado: "_corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)"
El JSON se ve así (No esta completo en este ejemplo, son muchas más lineas):
    {
    "1190418":{
        "166":{
            "team_details":{
                "team_id":"166",
                "team_name":"Huddersfield",
                "team_rating":"6.14",
                "date":"30/01/2018"
            },
            "aggregate_stats":{
                "won_corners":"1",
                "att_sv_low_centre":"1",
                "won_contest":"5",
                "total_tackle":"11",
                "aerial_lost":"15",
                "possession_percentage":"25.3",
                "accurate_pass":"214",
                "total_pass":"308",
                "total_throws":"15",
                "shot_off_target":"2",
                "total_offside":"3",
                "blocked_scoring_att":"2",
                "ontarget_scoring_att":"1",
                "aerial_won":"16",
                "att_miss_left":"1",
                "total_scoring_att":"5",
                "fk_foul_lost":"8",
                "att_miss_right":"1"
            },
            "Player_stats":{
                "Jonas Lössl":{
                    "player_details":{
                        "player_id":"131171",
                        "player_name":"Jonas Lössl",
                        "player_position_value":"1",
                        "player_position_info":"GK",
                        "player_rating":"6.61"
                    },
                    "Match_stats":{
                        "good_high_claim":"2",
                        "touches":"39",
                        "saves":"4",
                        "total_pass":"28",
                        "formation_place":"1",
                        "accurate_pass":"11"
                    }
                },
                "Terence Kongolo":{
                    "player_details":{
                        "player_id":"109117",
                        "player_name":"Terence Kongolo",
                        "player_position_value":"2",
                        "player_position_info":"DC",
                        "player_rating":"6.19"
                    },
                    "Match_stats":{
                        "touches":"30",
                        "total_pass":"20",
                        "aerial_won":"1",
                        "formation_place":"4",
                        "accurate_pass":"16"
                    }
                },
                "Chris Löwe":{
                    "player_details":{
                        "player_id":"101664",
                        "player_name":"Chris Löwe",
                        "player_position_value":"2",
                        "player_position_info":"DL",
                        "player_rating":"5.96"
                    },
                    "Match_stats":{
                        "touches":"38",
                        "aerial_lost":"1",
                        "total_pass":"15",
                        "fouls":"1",
                        "aerial_won":"1",
                        "formation_place":"3",
                        "accurate_pass":"6",
                        "total_scoring_att":"1"
                    }
"1190218":{
        "15":{
            "team_details":{
                "team_id":"15",
                "team_name":"Chelsea",
                "team_rating":"7.11071428571429",
                "date":"27/08/2017"
            },
            "aggregate_stats":{
                "fk_foul_lost":"12",
                "won_contest":"11",
                "possession_percentage":"56.7",
                "total_throws":"26",
                "blocked_scoring_att":"7",
                "total_scoring_att":"18",
                "total_tackle":"14",
                "aerial_won":"16",
                "att_miss_right":"2",
                "att_sv_low_centre":"4",
                "aerial_lost":"10",
                "accurate_pass":"500",
                "total_pass":"583",
                "won_corners":"6",
                "shot_off_target":"4",
                "ontarget_scoring_att":"7",
                "att_goal_high_left":"1",
                "att_miss_left":"1",
                "att_goal_low_left":"1",
                "att_miss_high":"1",
                "att_sv_low_right":"1",
                "goals":"2"
            },
            "Player_stats":{
                "Thibaut Courtois":{
                    "player_details":{
                        "player_id":"73798",
                        "player_name":"Thibaut Courtois",
                        "player_position_value":"1",
                        "player_position_info":"GK",
                        "player_rating":"6.6"
                    },
                    "Match_stats":{
                        "good_high_claim":"1",
                        "touches":"47",
                        "total_pass":"41",
                        "formation_place":"1",
                        "accurate_pass":"32"
                    }

Estoy trabajando en databricks y pySpark es algo de lo que aun soy principiante, una vez pueda leer el json, sabría como proceder con el análisis pero aun no lo he logrado. También intente poner  MultiLine="True" pero tampoco funcionó.
Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

@AndesR, has comprobado que hayas cerrado todas las llaves bien?

@DanielSánchez El JSON no lo hice yo y además es sumamente largo con hasta 260000 lineas, pero viendolo a simple vista no pareciera estar mal. Igual revisaré lo que pueda a ver que. Gracias
